# Cannot use remove() to delete a variable in r

Tags: r

I have successfully used the `remove()` function in the past to remove both datasets and variables. However, over the past few days I have been unable to remove variables, although I am able to remove datasets.

I don't know how to upload data to a stackoverflow question, but I can show you the code I used and the output I've gotten. The dataset is called `test2` and the variable is `verbcatTC`. I do not have the dataset attached. Below are four attempts to remove this variable, along with the warning message received each time. Then I run two lines of code to show you all that this variable exists in the dataset.

Thank you so much for your help and let me know if I can provide further information. Also, what other function could I use to get rid of variables in case I can't get `remove()` to work?

```
> remove(test2$verbcatTC)
Error in remove(test2$verbcatTC) : 
  ... must contain names or character strings

> remove("verbcatTC")
Warning message:
In remove("verbcatTC") : object 'verbcatTC' not found

> remove(verbcatTC)
Warning message:
In remove(verbcatTC) : object 'verbcatTC' not found

> remove("test2$verbcatTC")
Warning message:
In remove("test2$verbcatTC") : object 'test2$verbcatTC' not found

> head(test2$verbcatTC)
[1] Positive Positive Positive Positive Positive Positive
Levels: Negative Positive

> str(test2$verbcatTC)
Factor w/ 2 levels "Negative","Positive": 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
```

Comment: You are trying to remove a column from a data set?  Don't use `remove`.  It's more appropriate to do `test2$verbcatTC <- NULL`

Comment: If you mean removing an object from the environment, then use the function `rm()`. If you want to remove a particular column, then as @Rich Scriven mentioned, you `df$col <- NULL`

Comment: It is also *possible* to do `within(test2, rm(verbcatTC))`

Answer (score 7):

`rm()` and `remove()` are for removing objects in your an environment (specifically defaults the global env top right of the RStudio windows), not for removing columns. You should be setting cols to `NULL` to remove them, or `subset` (or `Dplyr::select` etc) your dataframe to not include the columns you want removed. If you just want the whole dataframe removed from an environment, then `rm()` still works.

Comment: Thank you so much everyone! My apologies for posting a duplicate question; it seems I wasn't using the right lingo in my search terms (e.g., "variable" instead of "column"). I really appreciate the clarification that `remove()` is for removing *objects* and columns (aka variables) are *not* objects. So excited to set a bunch of crap variables to `NULL` so they are out of my dataset, lol.